# force an element to drop below

Tags: html, css

I have two elements that need to sit below each other but I not able to style it correctly

**image at the moment:**

[image]

This is the image with **`position: absolute;`** on the **orange box**

[image]

This is perfect but not correct 100%. **The next image will display how the end result should look**

**This is how the final result should look:**

[image]

Comment: where is the fiddle ?

Comment: sorry man no fiddle its on a live site and its crammed with dynamic code that's why i was not able to make a fiddle, so maybe you could just let me know some suggested methods to achieve this

Comment: i suggested you on bottom. it's best way . i have done almost same like this on a site

Comment: i wrote you solution below , check it

Answer (score 0):

> put the orange box in a box with relative property.

```
.outer-box{position:relatve}
.gray-box{position:absolute;}
.orange-box{position:absolute;}
```

> By this your boxes with absolute position will never overlap each other.It will help you.